# Enabling Spring OAuth2 ResourceServer disables UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter

Tags: authentication, spring-security, spring-security-oauth2

I have the following in my `WebSecurityConfigurerAdaptor`:

```
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
        .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/login.jsp").permitAll()
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and()
        .exceptionHandling()
            .accessDeniedPage("/login.jsp?authorization_error=true")
            .and()
        .csrf()
            .disable()
        .formLogin()
            .loginProcessingUrl("/login")
            .loginPage("/login.jsp")
            .failureUrl("/login.jsp?authentication_error=true");
}
```

I have an OAuth2 client (written in PHP) and can be redirected to /login before getting a valid access token.

Then I try to enable my `ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter`:

```
@Configuration
@EnableResourceServer
protected static class ResourceServerConfiguration extends ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void configure(ResourceServerSecurityConfigurer resources)
            throws Exception {
        resources.resourceId("myResource").stateless(false);
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .sessionManagement()
                .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.IF_REQUIRED)
                .and()
            .requestMatchers()
                .antMatchers("/me")
                .and()
            .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/me").access("#oauth2.hasScope('email')");
    }

}
```

Once the `ResourceServer` is enabled, the `UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter` is never invoked, and going to /login returns the HTTP 404 error.

I read the sample Spring OAuth2 application sparklr2 and tonr2 many times but I cannot figure out what is wrong with my code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a very difficult bug to track down.

My code initially used Spring Security version 4.0.2.RELEASE and Spring version 4.2.2.RELEASE. Once I changed my maven pom.xml to use Spring Security version 3.2.8.RELEASE and Spring version 4.1.8.RELEASE, my code works.

It may have to do with the following bug:
[resource server security custom request matching ignored](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-oauth/issues/444)